# How do I stop Devise from delivering mails when creating a user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a custom controller that creates users, like this:

```
User.create! :blah => "whatever"
```

My problem is that it generates an email like when someone is subscribing and I need to generate a custom email with much more information. Is there a way to make Devise not generate that email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to still have the token generated, so my code ended up looking like this. This is a quick and dirty solution and could be improved a lot, but at least it shows the basis of how to do it:

```
user.confirmed_at = Time.now
user.save!
user.confirmed_at = nil
user.send(:generate_confirmation_token)
user.save!
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `new` instead of `create` and call `skip_confirmation` before `save`:

```
user = User.new :blah => "whatever"
user.skip_confirmation!
user.save
```

The `skip_confirmation` method sets the `confirmed_at` date, which will prevent the confirmation mail from being sent.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Feels like the "way devise intended you to do it" instead of the "quick and dirty" approved answer. Thank you sir.

Comment: This solution also confirms the user, which may no be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think devise sends an email when you create a new user unless you have confirmable set in your user model so I'm assuming you're talking about the confirmation email.

I'm not aware of a simple way to turn off this email but you could modify the body of the email that is sent.  All you need to do is create a custom version of the file [views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb) so that it contains the information you need.

Another approach would be to overwrite the [default mailer](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/mailers/devise/mailer.rb) that devise uses and set your own custom one in initializers/devise.rb by setting config.mailer to your custom mailer.  Then in your custom mailer you can overwrite the method `confirmation_instructions(record)` so that it sends your new email.